# actionscript 3.0 function calling using button click

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

im creating a simple flash playlist using buttons, in my stage i have 4 buttons which is button for song1,song2, stop and play. i have a working code for this one, but i decided to revise it because my previous code is like, per song they have each stop and play button,so i created this one to have a dynamic stop and play, i created a function for each song, the function will change the filename of the song to be loaded,

heres the catch, so i first pick a song, (either song1 or song2) then i click stop, then when i select a new song this error appears

Error: Error #2037: Functions called in incorrect sequence, or earlier call was unsuccessful.
    at flash.media::Sound/_load()
    at flash.media::Sound/load()
    at playlist_fla::MainTimeline/songSelect1()

i think its not calling the second function because i cant see the trace i put inside it,anyway heres my code, sorry for the long post,

**THANKS IN ADVANCE**

```
var mySound:Sound = new Sound();
var myChannel:SoundChannel = new SoundChannel();
var myTransform = new SoundTransform();
var lastPosition:Number = 0;
var song;

song1.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK,songSelect1);
function songSelect1(e:MouseEvent):void{
    song = "<filenameofthe1stsong>";
    mySound.load(new URLRequest(song));
    myTransform.volume = 0.5;
    myChannel.soundTransform = myTransform;
    lastPosition=0;
    trace(1);
}

song2.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK,songSelect2);
function songSelect2(e:MouseEvent):void{
    song = "<filenameofthe2ndsong>";
    mySound.load(new URLRequest(song));
    myTransform.volume = 0.5;
    myChannel.soundTransform = myTransform;
    lastPosition=0;
    trace(2);
}

btnStop.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK,onClickStop);
function onClickStop(e:MouseEvent):void{
    lastPosition = myChannel.position;
    myChannel.stop();
}

btnPlay.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK,onClickPlay);
function onClickPlay(e:MouseEvent):void{
    myChannel = mySound.play(lastPosition);
    myChannel.soundTransform = myTransform();
}
```

Comment: song1 and song2 do not appear to be defined vars are these on the timeline? also you should type song to String - var song:String;

Comment: song1 and song2 are the instance names for the buttons i created.. and for the String var song:String, even though i did not cast the variable song to a string it still works,, problems is when i click the other button that error appears,,,thank you for your response

Answer (score 0):

**Correction:**

[According to Adobe:](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/media/Sound.html#load%28%29)

> Once load() is called on a Sound object, you can't later load a
>   different sound file into that Sound object. To load a different sound
>   file, create a new Sound object.

So, creating a new sound object would be the only way to fix it.

*- - - Original Post - - -*

If you enable debugging in your flash settings, it'd be easier to determine exactly what line is causing issues.  That said, your code doesn't look incorrect apart from defining your sound transform twice.  Try this:

```
var mySound:Sound = new Sound();
var myChannel:SoundChannel = new SoundChannel();
var myTransform = new SoundTransform();
myChannel.soundTransform = myTransform;

var lastPosition:Number = 0;
var song;

song1.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK,songHandler);
song2.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK,songHandler);
btnStop.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK,onClickStop);
btnPlay.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK,onClickPlay);

function songHandler(e:MouseEvent):void {
    switch (e.currentTarget.name) {
        case "song1":
            songSelect("<filenameofthe1stsong>")
            break;
        case "song2":
            songSelect("<filenameofthe2ndsong>")
            break;
    }
}

function songSelect(songPath:String):void {
    mySound.load(new URLRequest(songPath));
    myChannel.soundTransform.volume = 0.5;
    lastPosition = 0;
    trace("Loading " + songPath);
}

function onClickStop(e:MouseEvent):void {
    lastPosition = myChannel.position;
    myChannel.stop();
}

function onClickPlay(e:MouseEvent):void {
    myChannel = mySound.play(lastPosition);
    myChannel.soundTransform = myTransform();
}
```

Comment: thank you sir @Atriace! ill also try this, i already came up a solution for my problem, i just place "mySound = new Sound();" and it work, i guess every time that i have to change the path i have to insert it, this is the revised function `function songSelect2(e:MouseEvent):void{ mySound = new Sound();
    song = "<filenameofthe2ndsong>";
    mySound.load(new URLRequest(song));
    myTransform.volume = 0.5;
    myChannel.soundTransform = myTransform;
    lastPosition=0;
    trace(2);
}`

Comment: sir @Atriace your code still has the error, but anyway thank you for your help, much appreciated.. thumbs up! :)

Comment: You are correct.  After checking Adobe's API, it clearly states "Once load() is called on a Sound object, you can't later load a different sound file into that Sound object. To load a different sound file, create a new Sound object." @ http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/media/Sound.html#load()